# How to call window.alert("message"); from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my own exception based on some condition and want to raise an alert when control comes in this catch block

```
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    //want to call window.alert function here
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a desktop-equivalent of `window.alert`? Or is this an ASP.NET app and you want a message-box to be displayed on the client?

Answer (score 36):

Do you mean, a message box?

```
MessageBox.Show("Error Message", "Error Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: No. The question is about a web app, not a desktop app.

Comment: On his first undedited question, the tag says, `c#` and `.net`.

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit hard to give a definitive answer without a bit more information, but one usual way is to register a startup script:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch(ApplicationException ex){
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"ErrorAlert","alert('Some text here - maybe ex.Message');",true);
}
```

Comment: @NayeemKhan - They hide that information in the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Answer (score 6):

if you are using ajax in your page that require script manager `Page.ClientScript`
will not work,
Try this and it would do the work:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(),
            "alertMessage", @"alert('your Message ')", true);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following extension method from any web page or nested user control:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void ShowAlert(this Control control, string message)
    {
        if (!control.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("PopupScript"))
        {
            var script = String.Format("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", message);
            control.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(control.Page.GetType(), "PopupScript", script);
        }
    }
}
```

like this:

```
class YourPage : Page
{
    private void YourMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            this.ShowAlert(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this :

```
 catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showError",
           "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);

    }
```

this will show the exeption message in the alert box

Answer (score 2):

MessageBox like others said, or [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) if you want something more arbitrary, but your use case is extremely dubious. Merely displaying exceptions is not something you want to do in production code - you don't want to expose that detail publicly and you do want to record it with proper logging privately.

Comment: I agree. Redirecting to a fixed custom error page after logging the exception is better practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand but I'm guessing that you're trying to show a MessageBox from ASP.Net?

If so, this code project article might be helpful: [Simple MessageBox functionality in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/AspNetMsgBox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this to show the alert message box in code behind.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Record Saved Sucessfully');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Hope it works for you..

```
`private void validateUserEntry()
{
    // Checks the value of the text.
    if(serverName.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    // Initializes the variables to pass to the MessageBox.Show method.
    string message = "You did not enter a server name. Cancel this operation?";
    string caption = "Error Detected in Input";
    MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
    DialogResult result;

    // Displays the MessageBox.
    result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
     // Closes the parent form.
        this.Close();
    }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Sakla Test');", true);`