# alert in class file of ASP.NET not on Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to give an alert message in a class file i.e. `.cs` file, instead of in the Code Behind of page. But any regular ways are not working to achieve the same!

Also tried [these Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803630/how-to-call-window-alertmessage-from-c)...

`ClientScript` OR `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` both asks for
 `Control` as first parameter, which I don't understand what to
 provide!

Is it really possible? :| If yes then...
What is available way to give Alert from a class file?

Comment: Downvoters, please comment and let me know mistakes

Comment: I've not downvoted the question, but I believe you've a lot of room to learn about web development, and also ASP.NET Web Forms. BTW, are you still in Web Forms??

Comment: what you mean _give alert in class .cs file instead of Code Behind_?

Comment: Also, I would say you need to format your question better. Why you use a quote formatting to talk about the issue yourself? :|

Comment: @Grundy, edited question, hope it's clear now!

Comment: I know how to achieve the same on page.. It is an part to achieve message box from .cs file, so what's wrong in that! btw, I think this question was not asked here before!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825165/javascript-alert-showmessage-from-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: surely not, that question talks about alert in **Code Behind**, and mine question is about alert in class file! please read it carefully

Comment: @Vikrant where is different? Code Behind is '.cs' file also

Comment: @Vikrant i guess Business layer calling from Code Behind, so you should not call this alert message inside business layer, you can simple throw exceptions, catch them in Code Behind and use `ClientScript` OR `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` like in solution by link in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in .net 1.1 so should work in newer .net frameworks

```
public class MessageBox
{
    private static Hashtable m_executingPages = new Hashtable();
    private MessageBox(){}
    /// <summary>
    /// Show Event for the Messagebox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sMessage">Pass String to Display</param>
    public static void Show( string sMessage )
    {
        // If this is the first time a page has called this method then
        if( !m_executingPages.Contains( HttpContext.Current.Handler ) )
        {
            // Attempt to cast HttpHandler as a Page.
            Page executingPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            if( executingPage != null )
            {
                // Create a Queue to hold one or more messages.
                Queue messageQueue = new Queue();
                // Add our message to the Queue
                messageQueue.Enqueue( sMessage );
                // Add our message queue to the hash table. Use our page reference
                // (IHttpHandler) as the key.
                m_executingPages.Add( HttpContext.Current.Handler, messageQueue );
                // Wire up Unload event so that we can inject 
                // some JavaScript for the alerts.
                executingPage.Unload += new EventHandler( ExecutingPage_Unload );
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            // If were here then the method has allready been 
            // called from the executing Page.
            // We have allready created a message queue and stored a
            // reference to it in our hastable. 
            Queue queue = (Queue) m_executingPages[ HttpContext.Current.Handler ];
            // Add our message to the Queue
            queue.Enqueue( sMessage );
        }
    }

    // Our page has finished rendering so lets output the
    // JavaScript to produce the alert's
    private static void ExecutingPage_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get our message queue from the hashtable
        Queue queue = (Queue) m_executingPages[ HttpContext.Current.Handler ];
        if( queue != null )
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // How many messages have been registered?
            int iMsgCount = queue.Count;
            // Use StringBuilder to build up our client slide JavaScript.
            sb.Append( "<script language='javascript'>" );
            // Loop round registered messages
            string sMsg;
            while( iMsgCount-- > 0 )
            {
                sMsg = (string) queue.Dequeue();
                sMsg = sMsg.Replace( "\n", "\\n" );
                sMsg = sMsg.Replace( "\"", "'" );
                sb.Append( @"alert( """ + sMsg + @""" );" );
            }
            // Close our JS
            sb.Append( @"</script>" );
            // Were done, so remove our page reference from the hashtable
            m_executingPages.Remove( HttpContext.Current.Handler );
            // Write the JavaScript to the end of the response stream.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( sb.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```